# Angular Material, make <mat-chip> clickable

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-chips from material.angular.io

```
<mat-chip-list class="categories">
    <mat-chip><a href="/publication/category/{{category.id}}">
    {{category.name}}</a></mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

If I click with the center button of the mouse the link works and opens another tab, but I can not open the link with left click.

I tried with class="link-overlapping", but still does not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the anchor at all you can just use `routerLink` directly on `mat-chip`:

```
<mat-chip-list class="categories">
  <mat-chip [routerLink]="['publication/category', category.id]">
    {{category.name}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: What about external links?

Comment: The router isn't for external links.  You'd need an anchor with an `href`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to style the <a> tag as a chip?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with routerLink? it works for me.

```
  <mat-chip-list class="categories">
      <mat-chip><a [routerLink]="['/your_path']">{{ data }} </a></mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this way

```
<mat-chip><a routerLink="/test" class="mat-standard-chip" style="margin:0; padding:0;">My link</a></mat-chip>
```

So that link is displayed at the bottom left of the screen when mouse is hovering.